# WordPress 4.6 custom theme not loading plugin css

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code in my header.php

`<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>`

The CSS from an installed plugin is not being enqueued. Do I need something in my functions file to have a custom theme load plugin CSS?

I also have `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in my footer and the JS is loaded properly. Just not the CSS.

Comment: The plugin should include the required CSS if it is activated. There should be `wp_enqueue_style` somewhere in the plugin files. You shouldn't include it manually in the functions file of your theme

Answer (score 0):

Is there any errors?

First of all try to look at plugin directory and find where this CSS is linked(enqueued).